# Can I Execute Log running Console Application in AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

I have one .net core application which I need to convert into the serverless component. This process usually take 5-6 hours for completion. AWS Lamba or state machine can not be a perfect solution for it as it will involve recursively calling function until the whole process complete.

I am also thinking of ECS as AWS Fargate. Please let me know if AWS has any recommended solution for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider AWS Batch. Fargate can also be a good fit - it depends on the level of control over resources you want to achieve.

Comment: If you just have a single instance of the console application to run I would recommend Fargate. If you have a lot of instances and you want to use a job queue then batch would be better.

Comment: Yes you can run this type of application on ECS Fargate.